# Как получить инфо про загруженное, но ещё неопубликованное на стене группы фото?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как правильно запросить от VK инфо о фотографии, загруженной на стену группы, но пока не опубликованной ни в одном посте?

Моё приложение загружает фото, сохраняет и получает его id формата `photo111111_222222`, где 111111 - id пользователя, под которым загружал фото, а 222222 вроде бы, id самой картинки. Предназначается это фото на стену группы с id 333333.

Через какое-то время пытаюсь получить от VK инфу загруженной картинки, методом [photos.getbyId](http://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=photos.getById), но в ответ — ошибки "Access denied".

id фотографий в этот метод передавал и так и сяк: и `111111_222222`, и `-333333_222222`, результат одинаковый. Жетон `access_token` вроде бы, живой — прямо перед этим вызовом нормально получаю информацию о группе.

Что я делаю неверно?

**Добавлено из комментариев.**

Вот ответ от ВК в моём случае, с цитатой параметров (токен фейк):

```
{
    "error": {
        "error_code": 200,
        "error_msg": "Access denied",
        "request_params": [{
            "key": "oauth",
            "value": "1"
        }, {
            "key": "method",
            "value": "photos.getById"
        }, {
            "key": "access_token",
            "value": "c1922f9bc0c5a66fc735a66ff4c0e92e5fcc0c7c0c0866bc9c195ab24772c7b"
        }, {
            "key": "photos",
            "value": "-38068238_284397690"
        }, {
            "key": "extended",
            "value": "0"
        }]
    }
}
```

**Update**

Инфа получается без проблем для фото на стене группы, уже опубликованных. Проблема — получить инфо о фото, которое загружено для стены группы, сохранено, но ещё не было опубликовано в посте на стене этой группы.

Нужно для получения превьюшки картинки в пост, который долго редактируется на Standalone клиенте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стал надеяться на ВК, и сохраняю инфу о фото, полученную сразу после её загрузки, у себя. Похоже, это единственный надёжный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Я только-что проверил у меня этот метод нормально работает можете написать кусок кода или url по которому вы получаете?

Comment: Вы проверяли именно с фото-на-стену-Группы?
Вот ответ от ВК в моём случае, с цитатой параметров (токен фейк):

    {"error":{"error_code":200,"error_msg":"Access denied","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"photos.getById"},{"key":"access_token","value":"c1922f9bc0c5a66fc735a66ff4c0e92e5fcc0c7c0c0866bc9c195ab24772c7b"},{"key":"photos","value":"-38068238_284397690"},{"key":"extended","value":"0"}]}}

Comment: 200 ошибка возникает тогда, когда пользователю не разрешен доступ попробуйте зайти через браузер там должно быть написано "Ошибка доступа"

Comment: Я знаю, что такое ошибка доступа. Непонятно, почему она возникает тут? Вариант:

1. Неправильный id фотографии.
2. метод photos.getById() не работает для фото на стене группы.
3. ???

Comment: вы через браузер попробовали?

Comment: Пробовал. Жетон работает, другие методы работают.
Подозрение, что у фото-на-стену-группы какой-то особый статус, и получить информацию о них можно, как-то иначе, чем я пробовал, вводя id фотографии.
Вопрос: как?

Comment: А вы проверяли с фото со стены группы, или с обычным фото на своей стене?

Comment: Я проверял на фото на стене группы и на таком все работает, но на 1_129207899 возникла ошибка 200, проверьте может в группе запрещен просмотр фотографий

Answer (score 0):

В методах вот тут - https://vk.com/dev/photos.getById написано:

```
Некоторые фотографии, идентификаторы которых могут быть получены через API, закрыты 
приватностью, и не будут получены. В этом случае следует использовать ключ доступа 
фотографии (access_key) в её идентификаторе.
Пример значения photos: 1_129207899_220df2876123d3542f, 6492_135055734_e0a9bcc31144f67fbd
```

Соответственно, в вашем случае, возможно, нужно добавить еще значения токена

Comment: На момент публикования вопроса этой возможности не было